# Count value in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, grep

I need help , i have a file `output.txt`

```
ttl 128
ttl 128
ttl 128
ttl 128
ttl 1
ttl 128
ttl 255
ttl 1
ttl 64
ttl 128
ttl 128
ttl 1
```

i need count how many times appear the same value in the lines of the file. The final result must be something like this:

```
ttl 128 - 7 times
ttl 64 - 1 time
ttl 255 - 1 time
ttl 1 - 3 times
```

I hope you can help me. I'm trying to use grep command.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sort, uniq are sufficient for this job. however to get the same output format as described in question, try this awk line

```
awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(x in a){t=a[x]>1?"times":"time";print x " - "a[x],t}} file
```

for example

- the connector " - "
- if count >1 show `times`, otherwise `time` without s.

output is:

```
ttl 1 - 3  times
ttl 64 - 1 time
ttl 128 - 7  times
ttl 255 - 1 time
```

:)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with `uniq` and `sort`:

```
<output.txt sort -V | uniq -c
```

Output:

```
3 ttl 1
1 ttl 64
7 ttl 128
1 ttl 255
```

Comment: and to transform that into the requested output: `sort | uniq -c | while read n line; do echo "$line - $n times"; done`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`sort`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sort) command to sort your file and [`uniq`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?uniq) to make it unique and count the occurrences:

```
 sort output.txt | uniq -c
```

Note: Only 'problem' is that the counts are in front of each occurrence and in your example after it.